# Multiple testing correction in a graph

Tags: regression, multiple-comparisons, graph-theory

I am doing some statistical tests over a graph. Namely, each subject in my study has a graph (composed of nodes and edges), where each edge has two different values (let's call them F and S). I am modeling the relationship between F and S. So:

F ~ S + age + gender

Thus, I generate one model per edge, where F and S are both unique to that edge. Given the graph structure, however, the F's across the network are not independent, nor are the S's. If S was a global (non-network) measure (ie- the same value for all models, such as age or the result of a psychological test), there would be a variety of methods that I could use to correct for multiple testing while taking the non-independence of the outcome measures (F) into account. These methods, however, seem to be designed such that the independent variables are the same across tests. Since both F and S vary depending on which edge we are considering, is there a suitable way to correct for multiple testing, where the dependence in F and S are both taken into account?

Thank you in advance for your help.